# Pull out information from between tags without unique classes or IDs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the content of a particular website and render the output so that it can be further manipulated / used in other mediums.  The biggest challenge I'm facing is that few of the tags have unique IDs or classes, and some of the content is simply displayed in between tags, e.g., `<br></br>TEXT<br></br>` (see, for example, "Ranking" in the sample HTML below).

Somehow, I've created working code - even if commensurate with the skill of someone in the fourth grade - but this is the furthest I've gotten, and I was hoping to get some help on how to continue to pull out the relevant information.  Ultimately, I'm looking to pull any plain text within tags, and plain text in between tags.  The only exception is that, whenever there's an img of word_icon_b.gif or word_icon_R.gif, then text "active" or "inactive" gets substituted.

Below is the code I've managed to cobble together:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
pageFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.url.com")
pageHtml = pageFile.read()
pageFile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))
table = soup.findAll("td",{"class": ["row_col_1", "row_col_2"]})
print table
```

There are several tables in the page, but none have a unique ID or class, so I didn't reference them, and instead just pulled out the TDs - since these are the only tags with unique classes which sandwich the information I'm looking for.  The HTML that the above pulls from is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td class="row_col_1" valign="top" nowrap="" scope="row">
        5/22/2014
    </td>
    <td class="row_col_1" valign="top" scope="row">
        100%
    </td>
    <td class="row_col_1" valign="top" nowrap="" scope="row">
        <a target="_top" href="/NY/2014/N252726.DOC">
            <img width="18" height="14" border="0" alt="Click here to download word document n252726.doc" src="images/word_icon_b.gif"></img>
        </a>
        <a target="_top" href="index.asp?ru=n252726&qu=ranking&vw=detail">
            NY N252726
        </a>
        <br></br>
        Ranking
        <br></br>
        <a href="javascript:disclaimer('EU Regulatory Body','h…cripts/listing_current.asp?Phase=List_items&lookfor=847720');">
            8477.20.mnop
        </a>
        <br></br>
        <a target="_new" href="http://dataweb.url.com/scripts/ranking_current.asp?Phase=List_items&lookfor=847759">
            8477.59.abcd
        </a>
        <br></br>
    </td>
    <td class="row_col_1" valign="top" scope="row">
        The ranking of a long-fanged monkey sock puppet that is coding-ly challenged
    </td>
    <td class="row_col_1" valign="top" nowrap="" scope="row">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The reason why I have ["row_col_1", "row_col_2"] is because the data served up is presented as `<td class="row_col_1" valign="top" nowrap="" scope="row">` for the odd rows, and `<td class="row_col_2" valign="top" nowrap="" scope="row">` for the even rows.  I have no control over the HTML that attempting to I'm pulling from.

Also, the base links, such as `javascript:disclaimer('EU Regulatory Body','h…cripts/listing_current.asp?` and `http://dataweb.url.com/scripts/ranking_current.asp?Phase=List_items&` will always remain the same (though the specific links will change, e.g., `current.asp?Phase=List_items&lookfor=847759"` may next be on the next page as `current.asp?Phase=List_items&lookfor=101010">`).

**EDIT:** @Martijn: I'm hoping to have returned to me the following items from the HTML: 1) 5/22/2014, 2) 100%, 3) the image name, word_icon_b.gif (to substitute text for it) 4) NY N252726 (and the preceding link), 5) Ranking, 6) 8477.20.mnop (and the preceding link), 7) 8477.59.abcd (and the preceding link), and 8) 'The ranking of a long-fanged monkey sock puppet that is coding-ly challenged.'

I'd like the output to be wrapped in XML tags, but this is not excessively important I imagine these tags can just be inserted into the bs4 code.

Comment: you should use lxml, in order to use xpath. beautiful soup doesn't support it. xpath is very powerful for this sort of things

Comment: What is the expected output here? Note that you can often make use of parent tags with ids or classes or other distinguishing attributes to narrow down on the correct table.

Comment: @symbiotech with CSS selectors and some experience with the various searching and generator methods of BS4 I've never had any problems navigating the HTML tree.

Comment: @symbiotech: Thanks a ton for the response and the proposed solution with lxml.  I tried the code you provided and unfortunately I'm getting errors when I run it - e.g., `File "xpath.pxi", line 223, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144836)` and `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid type`.  Since I've spent a fair amount of time trying to get the scraping to work using BeautifulSoup already, it might be good to try to resolve it with that method first - though I'm of course open to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try [lxml library](http://lxml.de/) and [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/), this is a hint on how your code might look like. You should probably make a better selection of the desired `<tr>`s, than I did without seeing the html code. Also you should handle any potential IndexErrors, etc..

```
from lxml import html
pageFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.url.com")
pageHtml = pageFile.read()
pageFile.close()
x = html.fromstring(pageHtml)
all_rows = x.xpath(".//tr")
results = []
for row in all_rows:
    date = row.xpath(".//td[contains(@class, 'row_col')/text()]")[0]
    location = row.xpath(".//a[contains(@href, 'index.asp')/text()]")[0]
    rank = row.xpath(".//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:disclaimer(')]/text()")[0]
    results.append({'date': date, 'location': location, 'rank': rank})
```